# Subset category in ML Server using rxDataStep

Tags: r, microsoft-r

How do I filter customer A using rxDataStep from ML server? Right now I only managed to find continuous varaible selection examples.

```
latency <- rxDataStep(inData = data, varsToKeep = c("ex_customer","timestamp","total"), rowSelection =  )

> df = data.frame(customer=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",4)), tansaction = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) )
> df
  customer tansaction
1        A          1
2        A          2
3        A          3
4        B          4
5        B          5
6        B          6
7        B          7
```

Comment: I managed to solve it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `rowSelection` argument to `rxDataStep` takes any valid R expression:

```
rxDataStep(df, rowselection=customer == "A"))
```

To make this data munging easier, you can also use my [dplyrXdf](https://github.com/revolutionanalytics/dplyrXdf) package, which implements a dplyr interface to Xdf files.

```
library(dplyrXdf)
xdf <- as_xdf(df, "file.xdf")
out <- xdf %>% filter(customer == "A")
head(out)
```